# How to solve SIP installation error?

Tags: pyqgis, installation, mac, pyqt, sip

I'm new to Python, and am trying to install Qt/PyQt for PyQGIS. I downloaded the PyQt and SIP packages, and tried to install them but have run into errors.

Installing SIP: As far as I can tell, installation involves 3 command lines: 1. `python configure.py` 2. `make` 3. `make install` I managed the first two steps, but cannot figure why the third failed. I get the following error message:

> Jocelynes-MacBook-Pro:sip-4.17 Jocelyne$ sudo make install
>
> Password:
>
> cp -f sip /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/sip
> cp: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/sip: Operation not permitted
> make[1]: ** * [install] Error 1
> make: *** [install] Error 2

I have no idea what Error 1 or Error 2 are, nor how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you work on Mac OS X, you don't need to install PyQt or sip, they are integrated in the [QGIS version of Kyng Chaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis)

[image]

QGIS use the Apple Python therefore you can use PyQt and sip outside QGIS with a simple `sy.path.append`

If you use the Homebrew version of QGIS, all is installed in /usr/local/Cellar with symbolic links in /usr/local/

Now, if you want to install PyQt yourself, it is not a GIS question but I assume that you use El Capitan and you know the problem of the System Integrity Protection (SIP) (explication of your errors, /System, /bin, /sbin, /usr are protected) and [How to Disable System Integrity Protection (rootless) in OS X El Capitan](http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/)

Comment: Thanks @gene! I can't remember how I originally downloaded QGIS, but they've released a new version that I just installed from Kyng Chaos which works well. Saves all the faffing around trying to install following these directions (http://www.noktec.be/python/how-to-install-pyqt4-on-osx), and I wasn't aware of the SIP issue previously.